# Unable to retrieve data from firebase by retrieve "number"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am newbie and learning how to create apps by using android studio and firebase real time storage. I trying to make a apps which can easily retrieve details from firebase, the apps stop itself when trying to retrieve details from firebase. By this layout: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZF9o.png)

```
    a=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.account);
    b=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    c=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bank);
    edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enteracc);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            reff.child("number").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String enternum=dataSnapshot.child("number").getValue().toString();
                    String account=dataSnapshot.child("account").getValue().toString();
                    String name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String bank=dataSnapshot.child("bank").getValue().toString();
                    a.setText(account);
                    b.setText(name);
                    c.setText(bank);
                    edt.setText(enternum);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
```

it that correct way to use the button setOnClickListener?

in Firebase the data will be like this:

```
number:
{
  "22508800018589":
  {
    "account": "22508800018589",
    "name": "CBS TOP TRADING",
    "bank": "rhb"
  },
  "11004600239812":
  {
    "account": "11004600239812",
    "name": "Kong Kit Lun",
    "bank": "rhb"
  },
  "11407100284908":
  {
    "account": "11407100284908",
    "name": "Tee Wan Yee",
    "bank": "rhb"
  }
}
```

Comment: "the apps stop itself when trying to retrieve details from firebase" - please add your error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child nodes don't have a `number` property, so this won't get any value:

```
String enternum=dataSnapshot.child("number").getValue().toString();
```

In fact, `getValue()` will return `null`, so calling `toString()` on that will throws a `NullPointerException`.

My guess is that you're looking for the number that is the key of the node. You can get that with:

```
String enternum = dataSnapshot.getKey();
```

---

As André commented, you will also need to loop over the child nodes under `number`. Combined that becomes:

```
reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
reff.child("number").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        String enternum=dataSnapshot.getKey();
        String account=dataSnapshot.child("account").getValue(String.class);
        String name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        String bank=dataSnapshot.child("bank").getValue(String.class);
        a.setText(account);
        b.setText(name);
        c.setText(bank);
        edt.setText(enternum);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Also shouldn't they be looping over the results in ondatachange?

Comment: Good one André.

Comment: After some changes the apps it works and did not stop itself, but when search the number "11004600239812" or "11407100284908" it will show details of "22508800018589"..  No matter what number been search, the apps will show the biggest number in firebase.

Comment: I have try few times, no matter what number I search it only show the biggest number in the apps. Is that i miss out some step? or the issue happen in the json file?

Comment: That seems like a new problem, since this question wasn't about searching. But my initial guess is that you're seeing the results of the fact that you're trying to search for numbers, but are storing the data as a string.

Comment: Yes Mr.Frank, i will like to use "search" or "retrieve" data from the firebase which i have upload as a json.file. It mean when I searching for the number 11407100284908 this detail "account":"11407100284908 ", "name": "Tee Wan Yee" and "bank": "rhb" will show on the result.